# htaccess mutliple rewrite rules for multiple domains

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, ids

I have multiple urls and want to redirect old urls to their new ones.

The code below does work, so for example htaccess is catching `www.domain-a.com/index.php?id=41` and redirects it with a 301 status code to the same domain with the path `www.domain-a.com/our-conditions`:

```
#301 redirect for domain A on a special id.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain-a\.com$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/index\.php$
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=41(.*)$
    RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}/our-conditions? [R=301,L]

#410 on for domain A on a special id.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain-a\.com$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/index\.php$
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=52(.*)$
    RewriteRule .* - [R=410,L]

#301 redirect for domain B on a special id.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain-b\.com$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/index\.php$
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=221(.*)$
    RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}/press? [R=301,L]
```

As you can see above that's a lot of code for just a few rules.
Now I thought that can be done better and I tried something different.

My idea was to have multiple RewriteRules for one domain. Usually that works just fine like this example here:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain-a\.com$
RewriteRule ^press/material/(/?)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/press [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^about/(/?)$ https://www.domain-b.de/impress [R=301,L]
```

Now i came up with this tryout:

```
#Multiple rules for domain A on a special id.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain-a\.com$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/index\.php$
    RewriteRule ^index.php?id=41(/?)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/our-conditions? [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^index.php?id=52(/?)$  - [R=410,L]

#Multiple rules for domain B on a special id.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain-b\.com$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/index\.php$
    RewriteRule ^index.php?id=221(/?)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/press? [R=301,L]
```

The problem here is that my conditions do not apply. For example `index.php?id=41` is just going trough htaccess and my application does say 404 (not found).

Can you help me out here to get my approach working?

Comment: Let’s start by _you_ doing a bit better, than saying “not working”. Please go read [ask], and then edit your question with a _proper_ problem description. That includes examples of what exactly is “not working”, and _how_ (404? 500? …?)

Comment: @misorude: Thanks man for the honest and good feedback.  I read the how-to and edited my question. You were right :-)

Comment: A RewriteRule only checks against the _path_ component of the requested URL - but you are trying to match query string contents as well now in that place, that won’t work. You still need to do this part using a RewriteCond, like it was done in what you had originally, `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=41(.*)$` (The `(.*)` part would allow _anything_ after `id=41` here, if that is not what you want, the regex there would need to be made more specific then.)